# Import json files from s3 into postgres RDS

Tags: json, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to make a script (maybe lambda?) **so every new json file uploaded to this s3 is also uploaded directly into a postgres table located in `PostgreSQL RDS`.**

The json in nested and contains lists of jsons inside, so it is not that simple to just parse it in Postgres. In addition, it has a changing number of columns, so a new file may add up a new column to the table. (If a file has a new column that didn't appear yet, I want to add it and put null objects for the rest of the table values).

How can I do it efficiently?

Comment: For the first part: You can listen to s3 events and invoke your lambda on putObject: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-configure-s3-event-notification/
I don't think you are giving enough detail on the second part to answer properly (although I would not be qualified to answer that anyways)

Comment: I did add some information, it is a little complicated so it can be answered step by step :)

Comment: @YuvalEzrati were you able to dump the json file to postgres?
I'm doing same but struggling. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you can write lambda to listen to S3 events and trigger a function when a new file is uploaded.

https://n2ws.com/blog/aws-automation/lambda-function-s3-event-triggers

One event is trigged you need to read & parse the file.

Now connect to database & run sql queries after generating them from the object.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for the importing to RDS process? because I don't know how many columns are existing in the file that I am running on and it may contain new ones as I said. This is the complicated part for me

Comment: You cannot have a blind import on postgre. That's why direct json/ csv wont work. You need to parse data according to the existing targeted tables before using either direct import or sql insert. You can always check object keys to identify column present in file Or if all columns are not matching the postgre table schema you can use noSql database.